# two table value get and compare and and display compare value in selecbox its fine but all value also dropdown i used seletize js for it

Tags: php

```
<select id="select-name" name="select_name[]" required="required" multiple="multiple">

    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "orions_mobile_repairing" ) or die( 'Sorry, Site will be activate with in 15 minutes!' );
    $issues = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM issues" );
    while ( $isssue = mysqli_fetch_array( $issues ) ) {

        $problems = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM selectbox where id=10" );
        $problem  = mysqli_fetch_array( $problems );

        $wcrarr = explode( ",", $problem[1] );

        foreach ( $wcrarr as $problem_key => $problem_value ) {
            print_r( $problem_value );

            if ( $isssue['id'] == $problem_value ) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $isssue['id']; ?>" selected=selected><?php echo $isssue['name']; ?></option>
                <?php
            } ?>

        <?php }
    }
    ?>

</select>
```

isssue table :  id ,name
selecbox table id ,name
issuse name is save in selebox table like 1,2,10
so i want 1,2,10 value seletize in selectbox but edit time user seletize value show in selectbox and also value in other value which not compare its also show in selectbox and dropdown show the unselect value 
its seletize js use

table 1:id name
1:battery
2:screen
3:charger
value store in second table as array like 1,3
when i edit page value battery,and charger show in select box its ok 
but 3 chager show in dropdown so user can edit the third problem or delete  battery 
and charger from select
i use selectize js where tags show in selectbox when i fetch from database in dropdown
and which select its remove from dropdown.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-/FoaPy6LUI6tt31v34sR4XS012w1FRFSy7OIQUSDTNY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to ask

Comment: sir now i edit my question please answer